# How do I get this to work in a docker environment - missing ext-zip extension

Tags: laravel, docker, dockerfile

I am stuck with these errors for days and I have tried quite a couple of Dockerfile configurations.

#### Versions

- PHP version: 7.3
- Laravel version: ^6.2
- Package version: ^3.1

#### Description

**Exact errors**

```
  Problem 1
    - Installation request for phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 1.11.0 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.11.0].
    - phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 1.11.0 requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system.
  Problem 2
    - phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 1.11.0 requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system.
    - maatwebsite/excel 3.1.19 requires phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.10 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.11.0].
    - Installation request for maatwebsite/excel 3.1.19 -> satisfiable by maatwebsite/excel[3.1.19].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    -
    - /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-bcmath.ini
    - /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-exif.ini
    - /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-gd.ini
    - /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-pcntl.ini
    - /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-pdo_mysql.ini
    - /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-sodium.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

My Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.3-fpm

# Arguments defined in docker-compose.yml
ARG user
ARG uid

# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git \
    curl \
    libpng-dev \
    libonig-dev \
    libxml2-dev

RUN apt-get update && \
     apt-get install -y \
         libzip-dev \
         && docker-php-ext-install zip

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install PHP extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring exif pcntl bcmath gd

# Get latest Composer
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

# Create system user to run Composer and Artisan Commands
RUN useradd -G www-data,root -u $uid -d /home/$user $user
RUN mkdir -p /home/$user/.composer && \
    chown -R $user:$user /home/$user

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

USER $user

# Run migration?
```

Answer (score 3):

As I experienced, sometimes it is so confusing to install a php extension.
Fortunately there is an awesome repository([docker-php-extension-installer](https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer)) for doing it painlessly:

```
COPY --from=mlocati/php-extension-installer /usr/bin/install-php-extensions /usr/bin/

RUN install-php-extensions zip
```

Also you can add any extensions without concerning about the dependencies.

Comment: If you are using docker-compose make sure that you add ` --force-recreate` flag.

Comment: yeah, I use docker-compose but it doesn't have --force-create flag

Comment: It is `docker-compose up`'s flag.

Comment: where should I add this flag --force-recreate

Comment: It should be like this: `docker-compose up --build --force-recreate -d`

Answer (score 1):

I tried a number of solutions I found and none worked for me -- including this one. I had to resort to editing the php.ini inside of the docker container and specifying which extensions I wanted to use. I don't think it was a problem of extensions not being installed, but the php.ini was not being updated properly for some reason.

[Here Is the article that helped me find php.ini](https://www.massolit-media.com/tech-writing/wordpress-and-docker-customize-a-container/)

This was for the PHP:8.0.3-fpm-buster docker image.